# Bitcoin deposit doesnt show up

Tags: cryptsy

The 21st of January I made a deposit from my Multibit wallet to Cryptsy. The amount was 0,43 bitcoin but this never arrived at my Cryptsy account. I have made deposits before and after and everything went fine.

Here is the information from blockchain.

http://blockchain.info/tx-index/ec0e3469720c4f4fad2353b798d051af81583205838753a8ad3c2ea960b25282

Does somebody know what to do?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe ask Cryptsy? We can't really help with this.

Comment: I did, they didnt came up with a solution

Comment: So why should we came up with a solution?

Comment: I was just wondering if anyone had some ideas what to do.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should be addressed to the Cryptsy customer service.

Answer (score 2):

As I went a bit to explore your transaction it is obvious that it is going to this wallet:

https://blockchain.info/address/1Ndo4EfFKi8f5jbHXEyuezgK9Mmb6f9uCV

I'm pretty sure that it belongs to Cryptsy.

All we can assume from those transactions is that you sent bitcoins to wallet where is a lot of trafic. So it is most likely that its some mistake in Cryptsy confirmation.

All you can do is get in touch with costumer support.

Answer (score 1):

Double-check the address that you sent the money to. Then get in touch with the Cryptsy customer service should you find everything else in order.